# Display latest image from folder dynamically

Tags: php, html

I have the following code that gets the latest image from a folder of my choice.

```
<?php 
foreach (glob('/home/pi/camera/*.jpg') as $f) {
    $list[] = $f;
}

sort($list);
?>

<img src="<?=array_pop($list);?>">
```

What I would then like to do is display the latest image as soon as it appears in the folder without refreshing the page. I imagine this can be done with jquery, but I can not figure out how. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Use ajax to periodically load php script, where you will have code to check all files in that folder. It can return json with all files and you can check, if there is any new file, and then you can display it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to periodically load php script, where you will have code to check all files in that folder. It can return json with all files and you can check, if there is any new file, and then you can display it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_files_in_folder.php',
    success: function(data) {
        // here you can compare old files with that you got in "data"
    }
});
```

And the file get_files_in_folder.php should looks like:

```
<?php 
    foreach (glob('/home/pi/camera/*.jpg') as $f) {
        $list[] = $f;
    }

    sort($list);

    echo json_encode($list);
?>
```

Comment: Given we don't know how many images may be present in the folder, it would be better to include the `array_pop` and only send back one image reference rather than a list of all images requiring additional filtering on the client side.